# FileNotFoundException on creating widgets examples

Tags: android, android-widget, filenotfoundexception

hello
I'm new to android and have been using this tutorial for creating widgets.

on trying to run the app, i get a FileNotFoundException as below:

Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ibm/android/eclipse/HelloAndroid/bin/resources.ap_ does not exist  HelloAndroid    Unknown Android Packaging Problem

though i get this error, the eclipse IDE does not show error in any of my xml and java files. Please help!

Comment: When you find any answer as right, accept it by putting the tick mark

Answer (score 2):

have you tried clean and build?

Comment: Select Project from menu and click on Clean after this right click on project and select Refresh